# How can i use tee to send all output to stdout and grepped output to file?

Tags: unix, logging, grep, tee

I can use tee to send output to both stdout and file like this:

```
./process.sh | tee output.log
```

How do i send complete output to stdout and grepped output to file?

This one won't work, because tee expects a second file argument:

```
./process.sh | tee | grep foo > output.log
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
./process.sh | { tee /dev/tty | grep foo > output.log; }
```

this doesn't send output to stdout, but to the tty.  Perhaps that is good enough.

or you could do:

```
./process.sh | awk '/foo/{ print > "output.log"} 1'
```

which prints all the output of `process.sh` to stdout, and lines that match `foo` are written to the file.

Also, you can do:

```
mkfifo fifo
./process.sh | { cat fifo & tee fifo | grep foo > output.log; }
rm fifo
```

That can be done more cleanly with a `/proc` filesystem:

```
./process.sh | { tee /proc/self/fd/6 | grep foo > output.lot; } 6>&1
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to another answer which redirects output to `/dev/tty`, if you use a shell (and an OS) supporting `bash`-style process substitution, you can do this:

```
./process.sh | tee >(grep foo > output.log)
```